# Find $f^{(100)}(0) $ and $f^{(101)}(0) $ if $f(x)=xe^{\arctan{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$$f(x)=xe^{\arctan{x}}$$

Part of my solution

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{(k)}(e^{\arctan{x}})^{(n-k)}=x(e^{\arctan{x}})^{(n)}+(e^{\arctan{x}})^{(n-1)}$$

First term probably disappears because $x=0$ but i don't know what to do with second term.

Comment: Perhaps use $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ and apply trig functions?

Comment: $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative, right? Not the $n$th iteration or power?

Comment: I can't use $i$ because we are doing real analysis and yes

Comment: :( complex numbers can be nice

Comment: Simple Art, aren't you high school student, how do you know these stuff :D

Comment: @RushThaMan Oh hush.  I just learn things on my own and this is where I get.  I skipped Calc I this year btw.  ;D

Comment: Here's what you do with really fun chain rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: @SimpleArt looks really nice, they could implement in psychiatric treatment for mentally sick people

Comment: I don't see a slick solution to your problem. This looks like it's meant to hint you toward using power series, but as Simple Art observes, that isn't so nice.

Comment: @SimpleArt it always surprises me how much people are surprised to hear of students in high school doing well in mathematics... I mean, this year I skipped a second year Algebra course as well as Calc 1 and Calc 2 due to self study (could have skipped to Real Analysis, but school system said no...) and I still consider myself fairly pathetic at mathematics compared to others... Wasn't Galois around 19 when he created his theory?

Comment: If only this had been $x\exp(2\tanh^{-1}(x))$, it would have been so easy…

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yeah, I get you.  I could've skipped Calc 2, but school system also said no.  And surprisingly, I'm kind of struggling, not because of the math, but because of the calculators!  They make us overly-reliant on the calculators IMO.

Comment: @SimpleArt The problem is the fact that the school system still uses the long out-dated TI Calculators.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein XD  Ikr?  And it takes me forever to do simple problems because I can't remember which buttons do what and stuff!  ugh, so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

See that

$$e^{\arctan(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\arctan(x))^n}{n!}$$

And

$$\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

which gives

$$e^{\arctan(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)^n}{n!}$$

Note that you only want the coefficient of $x^{100,101}$ (by Taylor's theorem), so we can safely ignore all things that result in larger exponents. (and the case $n=0$)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{101}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{50}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)^n}{n!}$$

I'm not exactly sure what you'd do from here, but it is somewhat hand calculate-able from here.

Note that since $101$ is prime, very few cases result in a $x^{101}$.  More cases arrive for $x^{100}$, but it is still within reasonable to calculate.

For $x^{101}$:

$$\left(\frac1{101}-\frac1{101!}\right)x^{101}$$

which is clear since no other combination of $n,k$ will produce $x^{101}$.

For $x^{100}$, the problem is much harder but not impossible.  The [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) provides light on the problem and lets it reduce down to fewer scenarios of $n\in\lbrace2,4,10,100\rbrace$ (using factorizations and the fact that $n$ can't be odd)

---

For $n=2$ (I only considered the coefficients of the $x^{100}$ term):

$$a_2=\frac{\frac1{1(99)}+\frac1{3(97)}+\frac1{5(95)}+\dots+\frac1{97(3)}+\frac1{99(1)}}{-2}=-\left(\sum_{p=0}^{24}\frac1{(2p+1)(100-(2p+1))}\right)$$

$$=\sum_{p=0}^{24}\frac1{4p^2-196p-101}$$

---

After some work, I arrive at the conclusion that for $n\in\lbrace4,10,100\rbrace$, the problem is too tedious.

Comment: I tried that but you have multiple products of sums which can't result in anything humanic :D

Comment: I am going to sleep now, wish me luck tomorrow at my real analysis exam :D

Comment: @RushThaMan Well, sure, but there's always the handy dandy multi-nomial expansion formula!  And note that if you actually sit down and try to hand calculate, you'll notice you can use some neat factorization tricks and the fact that 101 is prime to reduce the problem a whole bunch to mostly small values of $n$ here.

Comment: @RushThaMan I improved the answer to have the case $n=101$ and a partial answer for $n=100$.

Comment: @SimpleArt Hey there! This is a good start at a solution but I think I've spotted an error in your reasoning. You claim that there are only $2$ terms in $x^{101}$ in the series expansion of $e^{\tan^{-1}(x)}$, which seems logical as it's prime but the problem with this is that we can multiply by $x$. Take for example the term in the series at $n=3$. The term is $a_3=\frac{1}{3!}(x+\dots)(x+\dots)(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots-\frac{x^{99}}{99}+\frac{x^{101}}{101})$. Clearly we'll have a term of $-\frac{1}{3!\cdot99}x^{101}$ and the same would appear to be true for all odd $n$.

Comment: @Jam Yeah, I realized that over-night.  Then I realized that this problem just becomes overly-tedious then.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yeah ikr. I spent at least an hour on it last night before getting frustrated and I'm a bit fed up with it now.

Comment: @Jam Hey, we tried.  More of a coding problem perhaps, but then we may as well use wolframalpha.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ is the nth coefficient of the series expansion of your function.

We have
$$f(x) = x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(\arctan{x}\right)^n}{n!}}$$
and
$$\arctan{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}}$$
so
$$f(x) = x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}}\right)^n}{n!}}$$

to get the 100th coefficient we can look at the odd compositions of 99 (since we multiplied by $x$).

$$f^{(100)}(0) = 100! \left( \frac{(-1)^{49}}{1!} \cdot \frac{1}{99} 
 + \frac{(-1)^{48}}{3!}\sum_{a+b+c=48}{\frac{1}{(2a+1)(2b+1)(2c+1)}}
 \\+ \frac{(-1)^{47}}{5!}\sum_{a+b+c+d+e=47}{\frac{1}{(2a+1)(2b+1)(2c+1)(2d+1)(2e+1)}} + \dots + \frac{(-1)^1}{99!}\right)$$

I'm stuck here though. I hope someone knows how to simplify these sums.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

As you pointed out,
$$\begin{align}f^{[n]}(x)&=\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}x^{[i]}\left(e^{\tan^{-1}(x)}\right)^{[n-i]}
\\
&=x\left(e^{\tan^{-1}(x)}\right)^{[n]}+n\left(e^{\tan^{-1}(x)}\right)^{[n-1]}
\end{align}$$

We set $g(x)=\left(e^{\tan^{-1}(x)}\right)$, $h(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$ and consider $g^{[n]}(x)$.

$\begin{align}g'(x)&=\left(e^{h(x)}\right)'
\\
&=h'(x)g(x)
\\
g''&=h''g+h'g'
\\
&=h''g+h'h'g
\\
&=(h''+(h')^2)g
\\
g'''&=(h'''+2h'h'')g+(h''+(h')^2)h'g
\\
&=(h'''+3h'h''+(h')^3)g
\\
g^{[4]}&=(h^{[4]}+3(h''h''+h'h''')+3(h')^2h'')g+(h'''h'+3(h')^2h''+(h')^4)g
\\
&=(h^{[4]}+4(h')^2h''+3(h'')^2+4h'h'''+(h')^4)g
\\
g^{[5]}&=(h^{[5]}+4(2(h')h''h''+(h')^2h''')+6(h'')h'''+4(h''h'''+h'h^{[4]})+4(h')^3h'')g\dots
\\
&\quad\dots+(h'h^{[4]}+4(h')^3h''+3h'(h'')^2+4(h')^2h'''+(h')^5)g
\\
&=(h^{[5]}+8(h')^3h''+11h'(h'')^2+8(h')^2h'''+10h''h'''+5h'h^{[4]}+(h')^5)g
\end{align}$

Note that each bracketed term is a sum of the form:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}C_i\prod\left(h^{[m]}\right)^p$$

Where $C_i$ are integer constants and for each $i$, $\sum{pm}=n$. In fact, all sums of $pm$ equal to $n$ are represented as terms. For example, $3=(3\cdot1)=(1+2)=(1\cdot3)$ so there are terms with $(h')^3$, $h'h''$ and $h'''$. This is strikingly similar to the binomial series but I've yet to determine the constants. We would probably be able to use Faa di Bruno's formula for this.

We know that $h'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$, which we equate to a geometric series in $-x^2$ and generalise.

$$\begin{align}
h'(x)&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-x^2)^i
\\
h''(x)&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^i\cdot2ix^{2i-1}
\\
h^{[n]}(x)&=\sum_{i=n-1}^\infty(-1)^i(2i)_{n-1}x^{2i-(n-1)}
\end{align}$$

Where $(x)_n=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x-i)$ and $x^0=1$ when $x=0$.

Hence, $h'(0)=1, h''(0)=0, h'''(0)=-2, h^{[5]}=4!,h^{[7]}=-6!\dots$ and in general:

$$h^{[n]}(0)=\begin{cases}0&n\:\mathrm{even}
\\
(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(n-1)!&n\:\mathrm{odd}
\end{cases}$$

We may substitute this into the multi-chain-rule expansion of $g^{[n]}$(x) at $x=0$ using that $g(0)=1$.

$\begin{align}g'(0)&=1
\\
g''(0)&=1
\\
g'''(0)&=-2+1
\\
g^{[4]}(0)&=4(-2)+1
\\
g^{[5]}(0)&=4!+8(-2)+1
\dots
\end{align}$

The problem becomes finding the general coefficients $C_i$ of the odd terms in the expansion of $g^{[n]}$ but I'm unsure how to proceed.